Infinite number of decompositions into sum of four cubes
The context is the sum-of-four-cubes problem (see here).
I ask myself the following question (I asked a similar question on MSE). Do we know if any integer $k=a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3$ can be decomposed in an infinite number of ways as the sum of four cubes?
I've come up with a very elementary argument (in my opinion, not a new one!) which I think shows that many of the previous $k$ integers can be decomposed in an infinite number of ways.
The idea is to study the diophantine equation $$x^3+(u-x)^3+y^3+(v-y)^3=k\;\;(E),$$ by posing $u=a+b$ and $v=c+d$. This has the particular solution $(x,y)=(a,c)$ and is equivalent to $$(2ux-u^2)^2+uv(2y-v)^2=\frac{u}{3}(4k-u^3-v^3).$$
If we assume that $uv<0$ and $-uv$ is not a perfect square, then I haven't checked the details, but it seems to me that given two integers $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $(2x_0+1)^2+4uvy_0^2=1$, we can then prove that the generalized Pell's equation $$X^2+uvY^2=\frac{u}{3}(4k-u^3-v^3)$$ has infinitely many solutions $(X,Y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $X\equiv-u^2\; (\text{mod }2u)$ and $Y\equiv v\;(\text{mod }2)$, which shows that the equation $(E)$ has an infinite number of solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$, and therefore that $k$ can be decomposed as a sum of four cubes in an infinite number of ways.
This method only concerns values of $k$ such that $(a+b)(c+d)<0$. For example, how do we deal with the case where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are all positive?
Do you have any references to this or related questions? Thank you very much!

P.S. Along the way, by trial and error, and using the classic Chakravala method, I found an identity (see $(\star)$ below), surely anecdotal, but which I haven't seen anywhere.
Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $x_0$ and $y_0$ be any integers.
Let
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
A=(a-b)x_0+(d^2-c^2)y_0+a\\
B=(b-a)x_0+(c^2-d^2)y_0+b\\
C=(c-d)x_0+(a^2-b^2)y_0+c\\
D=(d-c)x_0+(b^2-a^2)y_0+d\\
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $A+B=a+b$, $C+D=c+d$ and :
$$\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}                                  
  A^3+B^3+C^3+D^3-(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)&=\\
3\left(x_0^2+x_0+(a+b)(c+d)y_0^2\right)&\times\left((a-b)^2(a+b)+(c-d)^2(c+d)\right) 
  \end{split}                                                                                               \end{equation}\;\;\;\;(\star)$$
It follows that if $(2x_0+1)^2+4(a+b)(c+d)y_0^2=1$, then $$A^3+B^3+C^3+D^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3.$$
By way of example :
We have $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=4$ with $a=-5$, $b=1$, $c=4$ and $d=4$,
$(a+b)(c+d)=-32<0$ and $32$ is not a perfect square,
we have $(2x_0+1)^2+4(a+b)(c+d)y_0^2=1$ with $x_0=288$ and $y_0=51$,
then $A^3+B^3+C^3+D^3=4$ with $A=-1733$, $B=1729$, $C=1228$ and $D=-1220$.

You seem to have solved your own question: for instance your last example shows that 4 is a sum of 4 cubes in infinitely many ways since the Pell equation has infinitely many solutions, and the same would be true for any other example.

Any sum of two cubes $a^3+b^3$ has infinitely many representations of the form $a^3+b^3+c^3+(-c)^3$. In fact it may be the case that every $k$ has infinitely many representations.

@Henri Cohen Thank you for your comment. In fact, I would like to know if, to your knowledge, this question has already been studied, especially in the case where $(a+b)(c+d)>0$, for which I really don't know how to proceed.

You are of course right, your method needs $(a+b)(c+d)<0$ and not minus a square.

According to Mordell's book (Diophantine equation, p.58), Theorem 3 says that
the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3=n$ has an infinity of integer solutions if there exists one solution $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $-(a+b)(c+d)>0,$ is not a perfect square, and $a \neq b$, or $c \neq d.$

@Tomita Thank you very much for the reference. Indeed, the condition $a\neq b$ or $c\neq d$, to which I had not paid attention, is important.

The very special case where $a=b$, $c=d$ and $-ac=\theta^2$ with $\theta\in\mathbb{Z}^*$, is easy to handle because for any $t\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k=(a+ct)^3+(a-ct)^3+(c-\theta t)^3+(c+\theta t)^3$.

@Tomita I've answered his MSE question using an identity. with the same condition $(a+b)(c+d)<0.,$ I don't have access to Mordell's book. Does he use an identity as well?

@Tito, No, let substitute $x=X+a, y=-X+b, z=Y+c, w=-Y+d$ into $x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3=n$, then
$(a+b)X^2+(a^2-b^2)X+(c+d)Y^2+(c^2-d^2Y=0.$
Applying the Gauss's theorem to this equation, we get the result.
Gauss's theorem:
"Given one integer solution $(x_0,y_0)$ of the equation
$f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy +cy^2 + dx +ey +f=0,$ where the coefficients are integers, there exists an infinity of integer solutions
if $D=b^2-4ac>0,$is not a perfect square, and if the discriminant=$4acf+bde-ac^2-cd^2-fb^2 \neq 0.$"

@Tomita. Ah, that is good to know. The identity I found is useful for finding quadratic polynomials to $x^3+y^3+z^3=t^3$ or solving the special case $t=1$ in the integers using Pell equations.  A different object then.
